# Extending Array.prototype returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'm trying to extend Array.prototype to include a square function. I have this:

```
Array.prototype.square = function(){
  return this.forEach(function(el){
    return (el * el)
  });
}
```

When I call this function on an array, say `arr = [2, 2, 2]` it returns undefined. If I add a console.log in there I can see that the callback function for the forEach function executes properly -- it logs 4 three times. Why is this function returning undefined instead of a new array of [4, 4, 4]?

Comment: The `.forEach()` function does not return a value.

Comment: NB: if available, use `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'square', { value: function() { ... } })` to prevent your function becoming an enumerable property of _every_ array instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method does not return a value. You need to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
Array.prototype.square = function(){
  return this.map(function(el){
    return (el * el)
  });
}

console.log([2, 2, 2].square()); // [4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Why is map needed? Why can't I use forEach? I'm really a javascript engineer so I've been trying to learn it a bit more. Forgive my ignorance here!

Comment: s/really/not really/ ?

Comment: @ChrisClouten `forEach` just iterates without returning anything - `map` instead returns a new array based on the result of calling the callback on each element of the original.

Comment: Lets say I wanted add a function called 'odds' or something. In a case like this could I use the filter method with a callback since that returns a new array or would I still need to use map?

Comment: @ChrisClouten Assuming you want `odds` to return only those elements from the array where `el % 2 == 1`, then yes, that's correct. `filter` is the correct method in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As p.s.w.g. said, `.map` is the appropriate function, but in a comment you asked about using `forEach`. To get this to work, you'd have to create a temporary array:

```
Array.prototype.square = function(){
  var tmp = [];

  this.forEach(function(el){
    tmp.push(el * el)
  });

  return tmp;
}

console.log([2, 2, 2].square()); // [4, 4, 4]
```

`.map()` is better, though.